# .net service - how to set more than 1 database in web.config

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, rest, wcf

I've created a .net service that work with a database declared in web.config file. Now the project evolved and i need to query more than 1 database, how can i do this in web.config and then specify the database i want to query in the c# files?.
Here's how the current database is specified:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="stringName" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UsrID;Password=bazinga;Application Name=AppName;Connect Timeout=20" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773611/connection-string-c-sharp, you should remove that password if it's real!

Comment: haha it's not the real password. thanks i will check that link! ;)

Comment: Not anymore right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just add another item to the `connectionStrings` section with a different *name* specification.

How your program calls the database is another story and I do not have the section of code which is defining the existing one. You would just need to find that and use the same method, just adding another variable to identify it.

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="stringName" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UsrID;Password=bazinga;Application Name=AppName;Connect Timeout=20" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="stringName2" connectionString="Data Source=XXXXXXXXX;Initial Catalog=DBName;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=UsrID;Password=bazinga;Application Name=AppName;Connect Timeout=20" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```